# How to delete from the dropdownlist if an item is deleted from grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a button, dropdownlist, Gridview on the page. On Page load I bind the gridview and dropdownlist from the same table.In girdview I have checkboxs and if I checked the checkboxs and click on button then it delete the selected rows. My problem is how I can remove the dropdownlist items which I have removed from the GridView.

Just like this I have one employee table. In dropdown list I bind empid to dropdownlist and bind all the field in gridview.

Dropdowlist

```
emp001
emp002
emp003
```

Gridvivew
columns

```
empid | empname | contact | des
emp001|   X     | 999     | XY
emp002|   y     | 888     | OB
emp003|   Z     | 987     | UU
```

On button click if I delete 'emp001' from gridview then I need emp001 to be deleted from the dropdownlist as well. Can anyone help with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind both Grid and Dropdownlist  again on Button_Click.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **RowDeleted** event on GridView

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted.aspx

When the row is deleted you get get the Id of the deleted row and refresh the dropdown list

Will it solve the problem?